# it is possible to convert a string to an object property? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

can convert a string into a property? 
I'm not very good with javascript objects, so I'd like your help ...

This is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/972fqz39/

```
var person = {    
  lastName : "Doe"   
};

var stringa= "lastName";
alert(person.stringa);
```

in this case it return `undefined`, i know that maybe i can to use `person.lastName`, but in my big code i can't use it.

So is possible to convert `stringa` in a property ??

Thanks!

Comment: `alert(person[stringa]);`

Comment: @JaromandaX WTF and that I continued to write person["stringa"] ! thanks a lot! if you write an ask i will check it

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+variable+as+property&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+variable+as+property)